# Search for common value, and group together

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I have a column with value:

```
+-------+-----------------+
| Input | Expected Output |
+-------+-----------------+
| A, B  | A, B, C, D      |
+-------+-----------------+
| B, C  | A, B, C, D      |
+-------+-----------------+
| C, D  | A, B, C, D      |
+-------+-----------------+
| E, F  | E, F, G         |
+-------+-----------------+
| F, G  | E, F, G         |
+-------+-----------------+
| K, I  | K, I            |
+-------+-----------------+
```

How can I get the expected output as in the table? it should iterate in each cell, and group the items together if there is 1 value common.

Comment: are they always in sequence like you show in the example? meaning can CD appear in the 5th row instead of the 3rd or are you looking at the immediate next row? Also please post the data as text

Comment: It could be in random sequence

Comment: @anky_91 network problem :-)

Comment: Treat each input like two or more nodes in a connected graph, and the expected output will be all nodes in that connected component.

Comment: This is a network problem. Checkout `networkx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can approach this as a network problem. Here's one possible approach:

```
from itertools import chain
import networkx as nx

df['Output'] = df.Input.str.split(', ')
G = nx.from_edgelist(df.Output.values.tolist())
```

We can find the `connected components` of the network using `nx.connected_components`. The only inconvenience here is that is is not implemented for directed graphs. So, since we want the output to be sorted by order of appearance of the nodes, we can build a lookup table mapping nodes to order of appearance, and use it to sort the components:

```
cc = nx.connected_components(G)
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(df.Output))}
cc = [sorted(c, key=lambda x: d[x]) for c in cc]
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'], ['K', 'I']]
```

Now we can set the `Output` column to a string containing the `edgelist` of a given component with:

```
df['Output'] = df.Output.apply(lambda x: next(', '.join(i) 
                               for i in cc if set(x).issubset(i)))
```

---

```
print(df)

  Input      Output
0   A,B  A, B, C, D
1   B,C  A, B, C, D
2   C,D  A, B, C, D
3   E,F     E, F, G
4   F,G     E, F, G
5   K,I        K, I
```